# How can I make my query more efficient?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have the query below, I have removed most of it because there are about 20 conditions and it will just be too long and complex to put in. My query works, the data I get is exactly as I want it which is my current year figures and my previous (ly) figures. This is achieved with some subqueries for the previous year where I subtract 1 off of the current financial year. Now, when my query gets more complicated and I add in say, 15 more of these subqueries, due to the amount of data I have, it can sometimes take over 12 hours to run. Is there a more efficient way for me to write this query?

EDIT

Not sure why so many downvotes on a perfectly valid question.

```
    SELECT
        period,
        finyear,
        fin_week,
        region,
        store,
        salesperson,

        SUM(Fin_Revenue) as total_rev_ty,
        SUM(CASE WHEN status_rev IN ('refund') THEN Fin_Revenue ELSE 0 END) as refund_rev_ty,
        SUM(CASE WHEN status_rev IN ('credit') Fin_Revenue ELSE 0 END) as credit_rev_ty,

          (
            SELECT SUM(Fin_Revenue)
            FROM [MYDB] r2
            where r1.store = r2.store
            AND r1.fin_week = r2.fin_week
            AND r1.Salesperson = r2.Salesperson
            AND r1.fin_yr = dateadd(yy,1,r2.fin_yr)
          ) as total_rev_ly,


          (
            SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN status_rev IN ('refund') THEN Fin_Revenue ELSE 0 END)
            FROM [MYDB] r2
            where r1.store = r2.store
            AND r1.fin_week = r2.fin_week
            AND r1.Salesperson = r2.Salesperson
            AND r1.fin_yr = dateadd(yy,1,r2.fin_yr)
          ) as refund_rev_ly,

        (SELECT
        SUM(CASE WHEN status_rev IN ('credit') Fin_Revenue ELSE 0 END)
            FROM [MYDB] r2
            where r1.store = r2.store
            AND r1.fin_week = r2.fin_week
            AND r1.Salesperson = r2.Salesperson
            AND r1.fin_yr = dateadd(yy,1,r2.fin_yr)
          ) as refund_rev_ly

FROM [MYDB] r1

        WHERE
        fin_yr IN ('2016')
```

Comment: It strikes me that including a `FROM` clause might actually encourage it to run.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, but the way it is now is very efficient! It returns an error message very promptly, and doesn't scan any tables.

Comment: I love how wiggy people get over this sort of thing. The FROM statement is in there now. Constructive help may be better placed than snide comments. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The case statement, makes your query to run in sequential mode and that makes it very slow.
You can change your sub-queries into this:

```
  (
    SELECT SUM(Fin_Revenue) as refund
    FROM [MYDB] r2
    where r1.store = r2.store
    AND r1.fin_week = r2.fin_week
    AND r1.Salesperson = r2.Salesperson
    AND r1.fin_yr = dateadd(yy,1,r2.fin_yr)
    AND status_rev ='refund'
  ) as refund_rev_ly,

(SELECT SUM(Fin_Revenue) as credit
    FROM [MYDB] r2
    where r1.store = r2.store
    AND r1.fin_week = r2.fin_week
    AND r1.Salesperson = r2.Salesperson
    AND r1.fin_yr = dateadd(yy,1,r2.fin_yr)
    AND status_rev  = 'credit'
  ) as refund_rev_ly
```

If you have an index *status_rev* column, the sub-queries will run much faster.

There are other improvements that can be made, but this is the least invasive one that I can suggest.

Comment: Would you be able to suggest the invasive ones as well? I am more than open to trying these out, or even to just be aware of them. Can you also explain sequential mode some more. Many thanks.

Comment: What I mean by 'sequential' search is that the database engine checks every single record in the table. So if you 10,000 rows, the refund sub-query reads and checks 10,000 rows to get the result and the credit sub-query does the same. If you define an index on status_rev column, each of these sub-queries will only read the rows that have the specific value in that column, which means the number of rows that are fetched are less. SQL server is using a very advanced algorithm for indexes

Comment: You can see what the SQL server is doing to get the result of your query if you use the 'Execution plan' of the query. This is a very broad topic, so I can't explain it here, but I suggest you read about it to know how to approach the performance enhancements in your queries.